# how to import moment file in LWC in salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, web

// HTML CODE

```
<template>
    <div class="dates">
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button class="link" type="button" onclick={goToday}>
                Today
            </button>
            <p>{formattedSelectedDate}</p>
            <p class="bold">{year}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button class="prev" type="button" onclick={previousMonth}>
                Prev
            </button>
            <span class="bold">{month}</span>
            <button class="next" type="button" onclick={nextMonth}>
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="header">
            <li>Sun</li>
            <li>Mon</li>
            <li>Tue</li>
            <li>Wed</li>
            <li>Thu</li>
            <li>Fri</li>
            <li>Sat</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="datePickerHolder">
            <template for:each={dates} for:item="date">
                <li
                    key={date.formatted}
                    class={date.className}
                    data-date={date.formatted}
                    onclick={setSelected}
                >
                    {date.text}
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

.js File

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment'; 
const today = moment();

export default class DemoDate extends LightningElement {
    lastClass;
    @track dateContext = moment();
    @track selectedDate = moment();
    @track dates = [];

    get formattedSelectedDate() {
        return this.selectedDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
    get year() {
        return this.dateContext.format('Y');
    }
    get month() {
        return this.dateContext.format('MMMM');
    }

    previousMonth() {
        this.dateContext = moment(this.dateContext).subtract(1, 'month');
        this.refreshDateNodes();
    }

    nextMonth() {
        this.dateContext = moment(this.dateContext).add(1, 'month');
        this.refreshDateNodes();
    }

    goToday() {
        this.selectedDate = today;
        this.dateContext = today;
        this.refreshDateNodes();
    }

    @api
    setSelected(e) {
        const selectedDate = this.template.querySelector('.selected');
        if (selectedDate) {
            selectedDate.className = this.lastClass;
        }

        const { date } = e.target.dataset;
        this.selectedDate = moment(date);
        this.dateContext = moment(date);
        this.lastClass = e.target.className;
        e.target.className = 'selected';
    }

    refreshDateNodes() {
        this.dates = [];
        const currentMoment = moment(this.dateContext);
        // startOf mutates moment, hence clone before use
        const start = this.dateContext.clone().startOf('month');
        const startWeek = start.isoWeek();
        // months do not always have the same number of weeks. eg. February
        const numWeeks =
            moment.duration(currentMoment.endOf('month') - start).weeks() + 1;
        for (let week = startWeek; week <= startWeek + numWeeks; week++) {
            Array(7)
                .fill(0)
                .forEach((n, i) => {
                    const day = currentMoment
                        .week(week)
                        .startOf('week')
                        .clone()
                        .add(n + i, 'day');
                    let className = '';
                    if (day.month() === this.dateContext.month()) {
                        if (day.isSame(today, 'day')) {
                            className = 'today';
                        } else if (day.isSame(this.selectedDate, 'day')) {
                            className = 'selected';
                        } else {
                            className = 'date';
                        }
                    } else {
                        className = 'padder';
                    }
                    this.dates.push({
                        className,
                        formatted: day.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        text: day.format('DD')
                    });
                });
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.refreshDateNodes();
    }
   
}
```

Comment: I am just want to implement a timesheet project in which i need to show datepicker

Comment: what have you been change in this code @sfdcfox

Comment: I just formatted your code to be legible with the `{}` code format button. That said, what's your question? Are you getting errors? Unexpected behavior? You should [edit] your post to give us more information as to what's going on.

Comment: when i am deploy this code to source org its give me "Invalid reference moment of type resourceUrl in file demoDate.js".

Comment: That error means you have the wrong name of the static resource, or you haven't deployed/uploaded it successfully yet. Also, see my answer for how to actually use the third-party script.

Comment: I am still getting the same error while update my code with your code " Invalid reference moment of type resourceUrl in file demoDate.js"

Answer (score 2):

```
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment';
```

Only gives you the URL for the resource. You still have to load it via loadScript.

```
import MOMENT_SCRIPT from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment'; 
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

And:

```
async connectedCallback() {
  await loadScript(this, MOMENT_SCRIPT);
  this.refreshDateNodes();
}
```

---

Edit: Please read [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library). I just realized you're attempting to use moment immediately:

```
import moment from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment'; 
const today = moment();
```

This does not work because your `moment`, as written, is basically just a URL (something like `/resource/moment`), rather than the already parsed and loaded script object. Unlike LWC components, third-party scripts using `@salesforce/resourceUrl/<name>` are loaded asynchronously, as demonstrated earlier in this answer, and must be explicitly loaded using the `loadScript` function that you import from `lightning/platformResourceLoader`.

> I am still getting the same error while update my code with your code " Invalid reference moment of type resourceUrl in file demoDate.js" –

In addition, you need to make sure the moment script is uploaded, and you'll want to verify its name. Check Setup > Custom Code > Static Resources and make sure the file is uploaded.

Comment: And in Moment Script file what should be there ? I am not getting properly

Comment: @singh_25 It should be the moment.min.js file, unless you need locale support, in which case moment-with-locales.min.js.